# Concurrent MPI programs / redefining MPI_COMM_WORLD

Tags: concurrency, fortran, mpi

I have a certain Fortran program which is parallelized using MPI. For a certain application I know want to run 2 fairly (but not absolutely) identical instances of this program. These 2 concurrently running programs would have to communicate with each other during runtime.

I thought one of the easiest ways to do this would be to define a global communicator (eg. MPI_COMM_WORLD_GLOBAL) which spans all the processes. I would then proceed to redefine the usual global communicator MPI_COMM_WORLD to be the total amount of processes used by this instance of the program (note that, although I talk of multiple instances of the program, there would only be 1 real program running in this case).

I would like to keep MPI_COMM_WORLD to be the total amount of processes used for 'this' instance of the program, as to avoid changing the communicators throughout my code.

My question is therefore, is there a straightforward way of redefining MPI_COMM_WORLD in Fortran? Or is my proposed approach bad practice and should I look into other methods.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MPI_COMM_WORLD` can be just a constant or a macro. Trying to redefine it is asking for trouble.

In my OpenMPI it is a `parameter` with value 9.

You would have to make your own variable with that name which shadows that one from module `mpi` or `mpif.h`, e.g., by using some custom module or include file.

It shouldn't be that difficult to refactor your code to use a variable for a communicator instead of the hard-coded `MPI_COMM_WORLD` using some modern text editor or IDE. With some tools it can be as simple as one global Search and Replace and declaration and definition of the constant (in a module).

Comment: I could also define local MPI_COMM_WORLD (with a slightly different name of course) and just use them throughout the program. This would however require replacing a lot of lines in the code. But I do understand your concern in redefining MPI_COMM_WORLD... I'll try to avoid it.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on performing such a shadowing? Whenever I try to do that the compiler will just tell me that MPI_COMM_WORLD has already been defined (in mpif.h)

Comment: Yes, you simply cannot use `mpi.f` then. Or at least not directly. That's why I recommend using different communicator instead. Just use a good editor or `sed` or whatever automatic search and replace tool.

Comment: This is a bizarre answer and should not be the accepted one. Both of the other answers are better. If you can not do `MPI_Comm_split`, use `MPI_Comm_spawn`: all spawned programs get their own `MPI_COMM_WORLD`, plus there is an inter-communicator that bridges them.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout What exactly do you find "bizzare"? Be aware that the acceptation mark is only a mark that the answer helped the OP and is no longer used to sort answers. Is a normal practice to ise a variable in any code for the working communicator instead of relying on a hard-coded `MPI_COMM_WORLD`. And the change is often trivial, just a Search-and-Replace. Yes, you can make other communicators using `MPI_Comm_Split`. And that is exactly my point!!! You may need to use other communicators, so use a variable for them, not the hard-coded constatant!

Comment: Normally, one uses a variable like `comm` or `working_comm` or whatever name one lines, not `MPI_COMM_WORLD`. It may save a lot of headache later.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout In fact, Wesley's answer is saying very similar things. I have no idea what you may find "bizzare". I just add a way how to solve that problem using a variable instead of a constant. Are you saying one should put `MPI_COMM_WORLD` all over the coded in one's call to MPI routines? I seriously doubt you are not. It is a horrible practice and it would be even more horrible to recommend it.

Comment: You advocate "change MPI_COMM_WORLD [...] using some modern text editor". That's what I find bizarre. "Are you saying " No of course not. The OP states that their code uses `MPI_COMM_WORLD` all over and that they are stuck with that. In that case @Hirsto's answer points out that using `MPI_Comm_spawn` makes it possible to have multiple executables with indeed each their own `MPI_COMM_WORLD`, and still the possibility to communicate between them.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout What you call bizzare is called "code refactorization". It is better done using proper tools. I find the need for spawning multiple executables with their own world a distracting workaround for a broken (or at least inflexible) code here.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you might be thinking of things (or maybe just describing them) in the wrong way. If you run two separate instances of your application (calling `mpiexec`/`mpirun` twice), your two applications won't be able to talk to each other without doing some extra work (`MPI_COMM_CONNECT`/`MPI_COMM_ACCEPT`). If, in fact, you will run both instances of your application using the same launcher (calling `mpiexec`/`mpirun` one time), then you should just divide your communicator in half at the beginning of your code by calling something like `MPI_COMM_SPLIT`. This will give you a different communicator for each half of the application and you can just use that communicator for your local (within one half of your application) communication and use `MPI_COMM_WORLD` when you need to do global communication.

This is the entire idea of MPI in the first place. You should use different communicators to create different communication spaces within your application. Everything shouldn't be done on `MPI_COMM_WORLD`.

Comment: I might have been unclear in my question in the first place, sorry. In the ideal case I'd like to use `MPI_COMM_SPLIT` to divide my global communicator into 2 and name the resulting subcommunicators `MPI_COMM_WORLD`, as this would avoid having to change stuff all around the code (I'm working on this code in a team so it's not ideal to go changing this everywhere).

So I'd like to call my global communicator spanning all processes `MPI_COMM_WORLD_GLOBAL` and the subcommunicators `MPI_COMM_WORLD`. But it seems that it's not trivial to do so.

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense. Then the answer to your question is, "Don't do that". Unfortunately, there's no good way of renaming `MPI_COMM_WORLD`. The rest of your communicators are relatively easy to do, but that particular one isn't possible.

Answer (score 4):

What you can do is have one copy of the MPI application spawn the other using `MPI_COMM_SPAWN`. When doing so, `MPI_COMM_WORLD` in each application will only encompass the processes in that particular application, i.e. there will be two separate `MPI_COMM_WORLD`'s - one for the parent job and one for the child one. The two copies will then be able to communicate via the established intercommunicator. The parent job receives the intercommunicator in the output parameter of `MPI_COMM_SPAWN` while the child job can obtain it by calling `MPI_COMM_GET_PARENT`.

Intercommunicators differ somewhat from the regular intracommunicators (such as `MPI_COMM_WORLD`). They are asymmetric in the sense that there are local and remote groups of processes in them and local operations are not possible. It is possible to convert an intercommunicator into an intracommunicator using `MPI_INTERCOMM_MERGE`.

The relevant logic in your case would be:

**First copy**

```
INTEGER, PARAMETER :: nprocs = 32
INTEGER :: child_intercomm, supercomm, ierr
INTEGER, DIMENSION(nprocs) :: error_codes
CHARACTER(LEN=40) :: command

! Spawn the second copy with nprocs MPI processes
command = './program2'
CALL MPI_COMM_SPAWN(command, MPI_ARGV_NULL, nprocs, MPI_INFO_NULL, 0, &
                    child_intercomm, error_codes, ierr)
CALL MPI_INTERCOMM_MERGE(child_intercomm, .FALSE., supercomm, ierr)
```

**Second (spawned) copy**

```
INTEGER :: parent_intercomm, supercomm, ierr

CALL MPI_COMM_GET_PARENT(parent_intercomm, ierr)
CALL MPI_INTERCOMM_MERGE(parent_intercomm, .TRUE., supercomm, ierr)
```

The code is a bit asymmetric in the sense that there is a parent that spawns another copy and that requires a bit of different logic in both programs. You can still call `MPI_COMM_GET_PARENT` in the parent and it will simply return `MPI_COMM_NULL`. That way your program will get to know that it is the first copy and do the spawn.

You can also name `supercomm` `MPI_COMM_WORLD_GLOBAL` instead, but you should notice that the `MPI_` name prefix is reserved for MPI calls and constants and you should not use it for your own variables.